# Disable auto-open new file in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Just like in title. Is there any way to disable auto open just created file in VS2010? It's annoying when i'd like to create few UserControls (XAML) and each have to be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no setting for this.

I'd like that feature too because `.xaml` files can take a while to load in the designer sometimes, when you don't even want them open in the first place.